# Eclipse is unable to find Snapshot.img

Tags: android, emulation, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I was creating a new emulator for ICS, but if the snapshot checkbox is checked, it gives an error that

> "Unable to find 'C:\Program
>   Files(x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools\lib\emulator\snapshots.img' files
>   to copy into AVD folder".

I think it is self explanatory.

So, what can I do to avoid that thing because I need it to start from a snapshot.

Comment: don't you have to make a snapshot first ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have Android sdk tools, android sdk platform tools installed in android sdk manager.

And then check if you have any of the corresponding images installed for the API version you are using.

Comment: Yes, indeed I have that's a minimum requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Its just because accidently you deleted emulatorsnapshots.img disk file from provided location. Try to retrive it from cycle bin.

If you deleted it by permanently I also stuck at same place..:-(

Comment: if you know how to again add emulatorsnapshots.img file to related sdk..please let me..thanks in adwance